# share image of compose component

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-jetpack-compose

i want to share image of my component , but cannot accses view of it, to share.
how i can accses view of my component or share image of it.
my component is a card

```
@Composable
fun CardItem(modifier: Modifier=Modifier,card: Card, onClick:()->Unit) {
Box(
   modifier
        .background(
            if (card.card_number == AllCardsActivity.NOCARD) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
            else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)
        )
        .width(CardWidth)
) {
    Column(Modifier.padding(25.dp)) {....
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'image of my component'?

Comment: @RezaFaraji i  want to capture a Bitmap of a composable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to share image of my component

If you mean that you want to capture a `Bitmap` of a composable for the purposes of sharing it, there are at least three libraries for this:

- https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable
- https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/kapture
- https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot

And all three are open source, so if you do not like them for some reason, you can examine their implementations, contribute back changes, etc.